# "Do not do A, or do B"

Tags: grammar, ambiguity

A sentence from [here](http://cwe.mitre.org/top25/mitigations.html):

> Do not accept any inputs that violate these rules, or convert the inputs to safe values.

Does this sentence prohibit conversion? Or does it encourage to do?
Note: I found [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270164/do-not-and-grammar-confusion), but I am wondering if the comma before "or" has some effect.

Comment: It's "This sentence does prohibit ... .", so it is "Does this sentence prohibit ... ?".
  "This sentence prohibits ... ." is , however, also correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this sentence prohibits conversion. If you do want to allow conversion, as I am guessing, based on the word "safe", you should replace "or" with "but". The comma reads as meaning you are listing a second "do not".

Comment: If you really want to exclude conversion, then you can change the wording ... "Do not accept any inputs that violate these rules, and do not convert the inputs to safe values."