# Separate Sentences combined with "and"

Tags: grammaticality, nouns, commas

I am new to this site.

I have seen a sentence like, "Do not do xxxxxxx AND maintain xxxxxx", where xxxxx can be any instruction.

Does the "Do not" phrase apply to both parts of the sentence separated by the "AND" or does it only apply to the first part of the sentence?

Comment: It's inherently ambiguous. Adding a comma after the first xxxxxxx goes some way towards disambiguating, but 'Maintain ______ and do not do ______' is best. (Or 'Do not do ______  while at the same time maintaining _______', for the other sense.) I'm sure this has been covered here before, but I can't find a precise duplicate. [Find ten apples and oranges ... do I find 10 or 20?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166286/find-ten-apples-and-oranges-do-i-find-10-or-20/166354#166354) is related.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Does this answer your question? ["Do not ... and ..." grammar confusion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270164/do-not-and-grammar-confusion)

Comment: If the intended meaning of *Do not do this and do that* were *Do not do this. Do that*, I would expect a **comma**: *Do not do this, and do that*. As it stands, I interpret it as *Do not do this and that together. However, doing either one by itself is fine*. For example, *Do not drink and drive*: *You may drink, and you may drive, but you may not do both simultaneously*. Another possibility is *Do not do this or do that*, which means *Do neither this nor that*. For example, *Do not eat too much or be inactive*. Again, there's *Do not commit crime, or go to jail*, with a comma.

Comment: As @EdwinAshworth pointed out, it's inherently ambiguous and therefore not a good example of a warning or direction. This is something you would ask whoever says or writes it about, because it's evidence of incompetence if it's intended to be unambiguous.